# Offset with resolution policy = showall

Tags: cocos2d-x, screen-resolution, cocos2d-x-3.0

When using ResolutionPolicy::SHOW_ALL as resolution policy, you get some black gaps on both right and left sides. 
I used

```
 Director* director = Director::getInstance();
 offset =  director->getVisibleOrigin();
```

for getting the offset (the width of the gaps), but offset.x and offset.y is giving always 0, so I wonder: How should I calculate the offset of my main screen?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this documentation, http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support.

I am not sure, but you don't want those gaps on screen, do you ?
Use relative coordinate, and you will be fine.

Also, if you want gap's width anyways, you can use getFrameSize() (Also on that doc) to get screen's actual display resolution , and do some calculations to get that width.

Comment: documentation is for 2.x , so you would have to translate a bit.

Comment: Yes, I fully read it. In the Reference, getVisibleOrigin() is expected to give you the size of the gaps, but it's not working when using SHOW_ALL. And no, I don't want to gaps, I thought I could move my sprites to the left to fill the gaps, but I can't.